# using join model attributes in rails has_many :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

as an example, i have a model Group and model User

they are connected with :has_many, :through => groups_users

groups_users table has an attribute, called moderator, specifying whether a user is a moderator of the group

question: how do i access all moderators of a given group?

after reading about :with_scope, what comes to mind is

```
def find_moderators
 Group.with_scope(:find=>{:conditions => "moderator=1"})
   @moderators=@group.users
 end
end
```

However, after rails 2, with_scope becomes protected, and doesn't allow given code in the controller, so What is the good alternative to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solved with

```
class Group
  has_many :groups_users
  has_many :moderatorships, :class_name => "GroupsUser",:conditions => {:moderator => true}
  has_many :moderators, :through => :moderatorships, :class_name => "User", :source => :user
end
```

Preferred to Matt van Horn's answer because this one produces only one query when we select user info with @group.moderators, while his solution gives separate query for each moderator

edit: updated to answer Sizzlepants' question. moderators created with this code should have moderator attribute in join model set to true (rails uses :conditions while creating join model), also, if i'd  have to code it now, i'd name groups_users memberships for readability.

Comment: I think using the :include => :user option on the named_scope would solve the multiple queries issue.
named_scope :as_moderator, {:include => :user, conditions => "moderator=1"}

But the has_many solution seems to fit your semantics better and is more elegant, I think.

Comment: Using this type of association, how would you create new users with the `moderator` attribute set to true by default?  I would expect something like `Group.first.moderators << User.first` but in my testing this results in the `moderator` attribute being set to `nil`.

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best method but I went with this one anyway.

Comment: late (very late) update to the answer to reply to SizzlePants question

Answer (score 0):

```
class User
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, :through => :groups_users
end

class GroupUser
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group
  named_scope :as_moderator, :conditions => "moderator=1"
end

class Group
  has_many :group_users
  has_many :groups, :through => :groups_users
  def moderators
    group_users.as_moderator.map{|gu|gu.user}
  end
end

# use it:
@moderators = @group.moderators
or
@all_mods = Group.all.map{|g|g.moderators}.flatten
```

Answer (score -2):

Monkeypatch!

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   public :with_scope
end
```

Comment: using named_scope is way better than doing this.